# Processing multiple CheckBox controls

Tags: vb.net, checkbox

I would like some help with a system I was creating that has 15 `CheckBox` controls. The system is such that at one time all these `CheckBox` controls can be checked at the same time or at least five of them checked at the same time.

I know how to handle it using `If[...]Else` but this seams tedious and will need too much coding.

Could someone tell me if there is a better and simpler way of doing it?

Here is how I am doing it and even before beginning the multiple selections on the `CheckBox` controls, I have several lines of code:

```
Private Sub computeCurrentSelection()
    If chkugalis.Checked = True Then 'ugali fish selected
        orderAmt = lab.Text
        total = ugalif * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " plates of" & " Ugali n fish " & total & " Kshs")
    ElseIf chkGitheri.Checked = True Then 'ugali dengu slected
        orderAmt = lab3.Text
        total = ugalid * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " plates of " & "Ugali n dengu " & total)
    ElseIf chkUgaliB.Checked = True Then 'githeri selected
        orderAmt = lab2.Text
        total = githeri * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " plates of " & "Githeri " & total)
    ElseIf chkPilau.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab4.Text
        total = chapo * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " plates of " & "Pilau " & total)
    ElseIf chkPizza.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab5.Text
        total = pilau * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " plates of " & "Pizza " & total)
    ElseIf chkMandazi.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab6.Text
        total = pizza * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & "mandazi " & total)
    ElseIf chkSamosa.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab7.Text
        total = mandazi * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & "Samosa " & total)
    ElseIf chkChapon.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab8.Text
        total = samosa * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & "Chapati " & total)
    ElseIf chkWater.Checked = True And chk300ml.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab9.Text
        total = water1 * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 300ml" & "Water " & total)
    ElseIf chkWater.Checked = True And chk500ml.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab9.Text
        total = water2 * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 500ml" & "Water " & total)
    ElseIf chkWater.Checked = True And chk1l.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab9.Text
        total = water3 * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 1l" & "Water " & total)
    ElseIf chkWater.Checked = True And chk2l.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab9.Text
        total = water4 * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 2l" & "Water " & total)
    ElseIf chkSoda.Checked = True And chk300ml.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab10.Text
        total = soda1 * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 300ml" & "Soda " & total)
    ElseIf chkSoda.Checked = True And chk500ml.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab10.Text
        total = soda2 * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 500ml" & "Soda " & total)
    ElseIf chkSoda.Checked = True And chk1l.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab10.Text
        total = soda3 * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 1l" & "Soda " & total)
    ElseIf chkSoda.Checked = True And chk2l.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab10.Text
        total = soda4 * orderAmt
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 2l" & "Soda " & total)
    ElseIf chkJuice.Checked = True And chk300ml.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab11.Text
        total = juice1 * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 300ml" & "juice " & total)
    ElseIf chkJuice.Checked = True And chk500ml.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab11.Text
        total = juice2 * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 500ml" & "juice " & total)
    ElseIf chkJuice.Checked = True And chk1l.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab11.Text
        total = juice3 * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 1l" & "juice " & total)
    ElseIf chkJuice.Checked = True And chk2l.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab11.Text
        total = juice4 * orderAmt
        subtotal = total
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " Bottles of 2l" & "juice " & total)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code I can see that it will only execute the code of the first checked `CheckBox`. Instead what you should do is separate your `If` statements:

```
If chkugalis.Checked Then 'ugali fish selected
    orderAmt = lab.Text
    subtotal = ugalif * orderAmt
    total += subtotal
    lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " plates of" & " Ugali n fish " & subtotal & " Kshs")
End If

If chkGitheri.Checked Then 'ugali dengu slected
    orderAmt = lab3.Text
    subtotal = ugalid * orderAmt
    total += subtotal
    lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " plates of " & "Ugali n dengu " & subtotal)
End If

....

lstReceipt.Items.Add("Total: " & total)
```

This way every `CheckBox` that is checked will have it's code executed.

Answer (score 2):

If you're a beginner, and your solution is working the way you want it to work, then there's nothing wrong with it.  Other solutions I can think of may be considered 'more complicated' than what you're doing, but would certainly save you lines of code.

I'm not sure why your `computeCurrentSelection()` sub uses an `ElseIf` rather than simply using a separate `If` statement per checkbox.  The way you have it here gives a strange priority system (for example, if `chkugalis.Checked = True`, then `total` will never include the calculations from the `ElseIf chkSamosa.Checked = True` line).  And so, perhaps all you're looking for is to take out your call to `computeCurrentSelection()` and simply replace it with:

```
If chkugalis.Checked = True Then 'ugali fish selected
    orderAmt = lab.Text
    total = ugalif * orderAmt
    subtotal = total
    lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " plates of" & " Ugali n fish " & total & " Kshs")
End If
If chkGitheri.Checked = True Then 'ugali dengu slected
    orderAmt = lab3.Text
    total = ugalid * orderAmt
    subtotal = total
    lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & " plates of " & "Ugali n dengu " & total)
End If
'Etc
```

Though, if it were me coding a solution for accomplishing what (it looks like) you're trying to do, then I would do it this way:

1. Create a `Public Class MyCheckBox` which `Inherits Checkbox`
2. Add two new properties to it:  `Cost` and `ReceiptText`
3. Change the current `checkbox` controls to instead be of type `MyCheckBox`
4. On the (form's?) load event, populate the new properties E.g.:

```
chkugalis.Cost = 10.45
chkugalis.ReceiptText = " plates of Ugali n fish "
```

Add all relevant `MyCheckBoxes` to a `collection` of `MyCheckBoxes`

Add a `For Each mchkb In MyCheckBoxesCollection` block to build your receipt.  Something like:

```
For Each mchkb As MyCheckBox IN MyCheckBoxesCollection
    If mchkb.Checked = True Then
        orderAmt = lab.Text
        subtotal = mchkb.Cost * orderAmt
        total = total + subtotal
        lstReceipt.Items.Add(orderAmt & mchkb.ReceiptText & subTotal.ToString)
    End If
Next
lstReceipt.Items.Add("Total: " & total.ToString)
```